# Is slicing and dicing of distributed counter data in cassandra using pycassa possible?

Tags: python, cassandra, pycassa

I read and googled a lot but could not find a way to slice n dice a counter data based on a condition. Is there a way in Cassandra to do this? If yes, pl ease help me with it.
For example:
If I am using a counter to store the total page views, is there any way I can get the count of page views of a particular page url OR get all page views on a particular date?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I'm working with a system that has both the features you are asking for. We are using HBase (not Cassandra) and we write the URL + date in the key for every counter.

Then you can easily get the two reports you are looking for.

To get all page views for one URL, scan for keys beginning with  and then add the counter values you find with that scan.

To get pageviews per day for one URL, scan for the key beginning with  + date.